# Автозаполнение мета-тега description в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, seo

Каким образом сделать так, чтоб тег wordpress в каждом посте заполнялся автоматически, беря первый кусок текста из самого поста, а на главной непосредственно из `bloginfo('description');`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `header.php` задаете вывод определенного описания в зависимости от условия:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php 
  if ( is_front_page() ) { // при выводе главной страницы сайта
    echo $post_description;
  } else {
    bloginfo('description');
  }
?>" />
```

Предварительно нужно заполнить переменную `$post_description` нужным вам образом:

```
if(have_posts()){
  while (have_posts()){ 
    the_post();
    $post_description = get_the_excerpt(); // например, используете цитату
  }
}
```